# HP 250 H6Q77EA Ubuntu

Tags: laptop

I have found a German retailer who is selling this machine at a decent price with Ubuntu installed.  They do not mention the version.  Questions

1. Will I have any issues (the keyboard I can live with) with the
   fact that the machine has been configured for the German market.
2. Does anyone here have any experience with this machine?  The only
   reviews I have found are from people in Germany - looks like it is
   not on sale anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone running into this thread.  The machine was so cheap that I got it anyway reasoning that if I could not make it work with Ubuntu I could always install Windows.  In the event though this was not required - the Ubuntu version is 12.04 and it appears to have been tailored for the machine by HP.  Upon firing it up it walked me through a few configuration steps and I now have an Ubuntu laptop that works well and looks good.